# ¿Cómo actualizar un listView en Android con datos obtenidos de Realm?

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment, realm

estoy haciendo una aplicación en android que usa tablayout y en cada pestaña uso fragments. En el primer fragment (donde tengo problemas) tengo un calendarView y un ListView.

La idea es que según el dia que se seleccione en el calendario en la lista se mostrará las clases que hay para ese día (Uso un modelo Clase).

Para el almacenamiento de datos estoy usando Realm.

Mi problema es que cuando pulso en un dia diferente en el calendario no se actualiza el listView. Sin embargo, si pulso en el primer elemento o en el segundo. Si se abre en otro activity (onItemClick) la información de esa clase. Osea, que aparentemente si cambia los datos en el listView pero no se reflejan. Por lo tanto, mi problema es ¿Cómo puedo refrescar el listView?

Ya anduve leyendo mucho por stackoverflow en inglés y en algunas otras pero no me funciona. (adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), lo de ponerlo en un hilo) Intenté varias pero aún no lo logro.

Gracias de antemano

---

**Solucionado**

El código ya está corregido y funcionando al final hago mención de la solución con la ayuda de @Jorgesys

Dejo partes de código:

ClasesFragment.java (Es la primera tab)

```
public class ClasesFragment extends Fragment implements RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Clase>>, AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

private CalendarView calendarView;
private ListView listView;
private static ClaseAdapter adapter;
private FloatingActionButton fab;
private static String day;

private static Realm realm;
private static RealmResults<Clase> clases;
private RealmResults<Clase> clases1;

public ClasesFragment() {

}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_clases, container, false);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    setDia(dayOfWeek);

    //Db
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    clases = realm.where(Clase.class).equalTo("dia", day).findAll();
    clases = clases.sort("horaClase", Sort.ASCENDING);

    //UI Components
    calendarView = (CalendarView) view.findViewById(R.id.calendarView);
    fab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab_add_clase);
    //Creamos adaptador personalizado
    adapter = new ClaseAdapter( getActivity(), clases, R.layout.list_view_clase_item);
    //Creamos listView
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listViewClases);
    //Asociamos adptador al listview
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);



    //listenners
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    //registerForContextMenu(listView);
    clases.addChangeListener(this);

    calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            setDia(dayOfWeek);


            clases = realm.where(Clase.class).equalTo("dia", day).findAll();
            clases = clases.sort("horaClase", Sort.ASCENDING);

            adapter.setData(clases);

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " "+day, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //muestro el dia
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"" +(long)clases.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RegistroClase.class );
            intent.putExtra("esNuevo", true);
            intent.putExtra("dia", day);
            startActivity( intent );
        }
    });

    return view;
}

public void setDia(int dayOfWeek){
    switch (dayOfWeek) {
        case Calendar.MONDAY:
            day = "LUNES";
            break;
        case Calendar.TUESDAY:
            day = "MARTES";
            break;
        case Calendar.WEDNESDAY:
            day = "MIERCOLES";
            break;
        case Calendar.THURSDAY:
            day =  "JUEVES";
            break;
        case Calendar.FRIDAY:
            day = "VIERNES";
            break;
        case Calendar.SATURDAY:
            day = "SABADO";
            break;
        case Calendar.SUNDAY:
            day = "DOMINGO";
            break;
    }
}

public static void update() {

    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    //consulta que devuelve todas las clases de la bd
    clases = realm.where(Clase.class).equalTo("dia", day).findAll();
    clases = clases.sort("horaClase", Sort.ASCENDING);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RegistroClase.class);
    intent.putExtra("esNuevo", false);
    intent.putExtra("dia", day.toUpperCase());
    intent.putExtra("id", clases.get(position).getId());
    startActivity(intent);
}

@Override
public void onChange(RealmResults<Clase> elements) {
    adapter.setData(elements);
}
}
```

Adapter

```
public class ClaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

private Context context;
private List<Clase> clases;
private int layout;

public ClaseAdapter(Context context, List<Clase> clases, int layout){
    this.context = context;
    this.clases = clases;
    this.layout = layout;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return clases.size();
}

@Override
public Clase getItem(int position) {
    return clases.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder vh;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_view_clase_item, null);

        vh = new ViewHolder();

        vh.nombreClase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewClaseNombre);
        vh.horaClase = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewClaseHora);
        vh.duracion = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewClaseDuracion) ;


        convertView.setTag(vh);
    } else {
        vh = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    Clase clase = clases.get(position);

    vh.nombreClase.setText(clase.getNombreDeClase());
    vh.horaClase.setText(clase.getHoraClase());
    vh.duracion.setText(clase.getDuracion());

    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder{
    TextView nombreClase;
    TextView horaClase;
    TextView duracion;

}
//Este fue el metodo que agregue y lo mando a llamar cuando ocurre un evento en el calendario
public void setData(RealmResults<Clase> clases) {
    this.clases = clases;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

Clase.java (modelo)

```
public class Clase extends RealmObject{

@PrimaryKey
private int id;
@Required
private String nombreDeClase;
private String profesor;
private String aula;
@Required
private String duracion;
@Required
private String horaClase;
private String dia;



public Clase(){
    //Required for Realm
}

public Clase(String nombreDeClase, String profesor, String aula, String duracion, String horaClase, String dia){
    this.id = App.ClaseID.incrementAndGet();
    this.nombreDeClase = nombreDeClase;
    this.profesor = profesor;
    this.aula = aula;
    this.duracion = duracion;
    this.horaClase = horaClase;
    this.dia = dia;
}
getters / setters
```

**Solución**

Para solucionar mi problema hicé lo que me recomendó @Jorgesys, creé un método setData en el adapter tal y como él lo menciona. Me quedó así:

```
public void setData(RealmResults<Clase> clases) {
    this.clases = clases;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Luego en la parte donde se dispara el evento del calendario me quedó así:

```
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            int dayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
            setDia(dayOfWeek);

            //cargo mi RealmResult con una nueva consulta
            clases = realm.where(Clase.class).equalTo("dia", day).findAll();
            clases = clases.sort("horaClase", Sort.ASCENDING); //ordeno
            //mando a llamar el metodo del adapter para actualizar el list view
            adapter.setData(clases);

            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " "+day, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //muestro el dia
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"" +(long)clases.size(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

A resumidas cuenta apliqúe eso para que me funcionará. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recuerda que no es únicamente llamar `notifyDataSetChanged()` :

```
@Override
public void onChange(RealmResults<Clase> element) {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Debes configurar el adapter a tu ListView **con los nuevos datos** y posteriormente llamar `notifyDataChanged()`:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataChanged();
```

o simplemente

```
((BaseAdapter) listView.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

Revisando tu Adapter podrías realizar también agregar un método el cual reciba la nueva lista de objetos y actualizar!

```
   public void setData(RealmResults<Clase> clases) {
        this.clases = clases;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Llamar este método, el cual internamente llama `notifyDataSetChanged()`:

```
@Override
public void onChange(RealmResults<Clase> elements) {
     setData(elements);
    //adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: Podrías darme un ejemplo, por favor?

Comment: @GerardoVazquez una pregunta en verdad esta funcionando y carga los datos al inicio? veo que el adapter recibe una lista de objetos clase "public ClaseAdapter(Context context, List<Clase> clases, int layout) "  pero veo que lo que envias es  RealmResults<Clase> clases no List<Clase> clases!

Comment: Si, si me cargan los datos al inicio pero cuando selecciono otro día no se refresca el ListView. Qué crees que pueda ser? Llevo checandolo toda la mañana de hoy :c

Comment: agregaste el método que sugiero en mi respuesta?  setData(elements);

Comment: Lo pruebo y te aviso en un rato

Comment: me sirvió lo del método setData en el adapter, también quité en el constructor del fragment donde sacaba el día y lo puse en el onCreateView del fragment y con eso funcionó! Te lo agradezco. Muchas Gracias me has salvado amigo!          En un momento actualizaré el código por si a alguien más le sirve.

Comment: @GerardoVazquez Excelente, me da gusto haya funcionado Gerardo, saludos! ᕦ /͠- ‿ ͝-\ ᕥ