# Recargar ListView desde Adapter

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Tengo un ListView en mi aplicacion Android manejado mediante un adapter, en el mismo, tengo un boton de eliminar items. Elimina todo bien, pero para poder ver los cambios en el ListView, tengo que salir y volver a cargar la actividad. ¿Hay alguna manera de recargar la informacion desde el getView?. Les dejo mi codigo:

Codigo Activity

```
public class gestionCategorias extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ListView listaCategorias;
    private SQLAdmin sql;
    private ArrayList<CategoriasModel> arrayCat;
    private ImageButton delete;
    private CategoriaAdapter adapter;
    private EditText agregarCategoriaInput;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gestion_categorias);

        listaCategorias = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listaCategorias);
        arrayCat = new ArrayList<>();

        sql = new SQLAdmin(this);
        delete = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.eliminarCategoria);
        agregarCategoriaInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.agregarCategoriaInput);

        loadDataInListView();


    }


    public void loadDataInListView() {
        arrayCat = sql.getAllCategorias();
        adapter = new CategoriaAdapter(this, arrayCat);
        listaCategorias.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
```

Y el codigo del adapter es este (Sacando el resto de metodos que no vienen al caso) => La idea es que se actualice la lista, o se refresque, al hacer click en el boton de eliminar

```
public class CategoriaAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private ArrayList<CategoriasModel>arrayList;

public CategoriaAdapter (Context context, ArrayList<CategoriasModel>arrayList){
    this.context = context;
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
}


    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.categorialv , null);

        final SQLAdmin sql = new SQLAdmin(context.getApplicationContext());

        final TextView categoria_nombre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nombreCategoria);

        final CategoriasModel categoriasModel = arrayList.get(position);

        categoria_nombre.setText(categoriasModel.getNombre());

        ImageButton eliminar = (ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.eliminarCategoria);

        eliminar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                                sql.eliminarCategoria(arrayList.get(position).getId());
                                Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext() , "Categoria eliminada" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Muchas gracias!

Comment: Adjunto un link donde un usuario antes ya realizo la misma pregunta: [Link Aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/69243/c%C3%B3mo-actualizar-un-listview-en-android-con-datos-obtenidos-de-realm) si no te ayudase esa respuesta adjunto el siguiente link que espero que ayude en algo, tambien de otro usuario de stackoverdflow que realizo la misma pregunta: [Link Aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250770/how-to-refresh-android-listview)  te dejo un tercer link donde podrás encontrar informacion al respecto: [link](https://codigoscript.com/2015/04/16/como-actualizar-un-listview/)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes probar con esto:

```
public void onClick(View v) 
{
sql.eliminarCategoria(arrayList.get(position).getId());
Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext() , "Categoria eliminada" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 arrayList.remove(position);
 notifyItemRemoved(position);
}
```